# Rust Tonic gRPC: Cannot access functions in generated file

Tags: rust, tonic

Please, I have a microservice written in Rust that uses Tonic (gRPC) to access a SQL Server database. I have validated the versions and files, but I am unable to access the internal functions of the file generated by Tonic.

I get the following error when trying to compile my code:
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module vehicleservice –> src/main.rs:9:5 9 | use vehicleservice::vehicle_service_server::{VehicleServiceServer, VehicleService}; | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module vehicleservice help: there is a crate or module with a similar name 9 | use VehicleService::vehicle_service_server::{VehicleServiceServer, VehicleService};

Here is the relevant part of my `main.rs` file:

```
include!(concat!(env!(“OUT_DIR”), “/vehicleservice.rs”)); 
use tonic::{transport::Server, Request, Response, Status}; 
use uuid::Uuid; use tiberius::{Client, Config}; 
use tokio::net::TcpStream; 
use tokio_util::compat::TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt; 
use async_trait::async_trait; 
use vehicleservice::vehicle_service_server::{VehicleServiceServer, VehicleService}; 
use vehicleservice::{Vehicle, ListVehiclesResponse};
```

And here is the relevant part of my `vehicleservice.rs` file generated by Tonic:

```
   pub mod vehicle_service_server {
    #![allow(unused_variables, dead_code, missing_docs, clippy::let_unit_value)]
    use tonic::codegen::*;
    /// Generated trait containing gRPC methods that should be implemented for use with VehicleServiceServer.
    #[async_trait]
    pub trait VehicleService: Send + Sync + 'static {
        async fn list_vehicles(
            &self,
            request: tonic::Request<()>,
        ) -> std::result::Result<
            tonic::Response<super::ListVehiclesResponse>,
            tonic::Status,
        >;
    }
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct VehicleServiceServer<T: VehicleService> {
        inner: _Inner<T>,
        accept_compression_encodings: EnabledCompressionEncodings,
        send_compression_encodings: EnabledCompressionEncodings,
        max_decoding_message_size: Option<usize>,
        max_encoding_message_size: Option<usize>,
    }
```

I have tried checking if the `vehicleservice.rs` file is in the correct directory and if the `include!` statement is pointing to the correct path. I have also tried checking if the module name is correct and matches the file name. I have tried recompiling the gRPC service definition file to ensure that the `vehicleservice.rs` file is generated correctly. I have also checked if my `build.rs` file is correctly configured to generate the `vehicleservice.rs` file. I have tried updating all my dependencies to the latest versions. I have even tried creating a minimal test project with only the necessary code to reproduce the problem. However, none of these solutions have worked.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to fix this problem?